# event handler for new class c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, event-handling, custom-controls

I make this class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI;
namespace Class1
{
    [
    ToolboxData("<{0}:Class1 runat=\"server\"> </{0}:Class1>")
    ]
public class Class1 : TextBox  
{
    public Class1()
    {
    }
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = "Click me ... ";
        btn.RenderControl(writer);
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        base.Render(writer);
    }
    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }
 }
}
```

but event for  `btn_Click` not firing ?

Answer (score 0):

The `Button` you have defined does not belong in the Controls collection and so it is only rendered as an `<input>` tag and never processed for event validation.

It is important to note that in order for the controls events to be linked up automatically it must have the same ID, and must be created by the Load event. To do so override the `CreateChildControls` method and give it a unique ID.

```
    private Button btn;

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();

        btn = new Button();
        btn.ID = "btnClickMe";
        btn.Text = "Click me ... ";            
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        Controls.Add(btn);
    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }
```

I would also recommend storing a reference to the button as a private instance variable to make it easier to work with.

As an aside, you might find it easier to extend a `Panel` instead of a `TextBox` as i'm not sure how a `Button` will render inside of a `TextBox`

For more information on the Page Life Cycle:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(VS.100).aspx

Comment: tanks for u. CreateChildControls firing in my code but not show any button in result. i used btn.Visible = true but not work

Comment: That's probably because you are extending a `TextBox`. Try extending a `Panel` instead (you can also add a TextBox to it)

Comment: Also you may need to call `EnsureChildControls()` in `PreRender`